# Can we add an Ubuntu partition to a drive containing a Windows 10 storage pool?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

About a year ago we had set up a Windows 10 machine (for gaming) with a 250 GB SSD and a  3 TB hard drive where only 2 TB were partitioned for Windows. This machine should now also dual boot to Ubuntu. No issue to shrink the SSD to hold Ubuntu - that went smooth.

But from Ubuntu we have no access to the 3 TB hard drive. It turned out that on installing Windows 10 we accidentally created a single 2 TB "storage pool" on that drive instead.

Of course we did not hibernate, fast boot is turned off, no encryption involved. Still, from gparted the whole 3 TB drive shows up as unknown 2.73 TB:

[image]

Is there any solution for this? Is it at all possible that we add an extra Ubuntu-accessible partition to our drive?

Comment: Sounds like this should probably be fixed on the Windows side. You might be better off asking on [su] instead.

Comment: I'm just assuming this pool thing is a Windows feature and not LVM. If I'm right,  doubt we'll be able to help. Since they have both Linux and Windows folks on [su], I figure your chances are better there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is impossible to add a partition to a drive being a member of a Windows "Storage Space" or "Storage Pool" as this is for physical drives rather than partitions (similar to a RAID). There also is no way to get access to such a Storage Space from Ubuntu.

To make use of the drive we have no other choice than to backup all files of that drive to an external disk, reformat the drive with a traditional partition scheme, and restore the files form backup.

How this is done in Windows is shown in my [corresponding Q&A on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1411233/can-we-add-a-linux-partition-on-a-drive-containing-a-windows-10-storage-pool).